# Kivy/KivyMD - Button does not react

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, kivymd

I have tried to write code using Kivy/KivyMD libraries after a break and I noted that I cannot make buttons to work. There is no reaction even when I use the old code I know was working fine.

There is no reaction after I click a button and I have this issue with both Kivy and KivyMD buttons.

Here is a sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ButtonApp(App):

    def build(self):

        btn = Button(text="Push Me !",
                     font_size="20sp",
                     background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     size=(32, 32),
                     size_hint=(.2, .2),
                     pos=(300, 250))

        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        return btn

    def callback(self, event):
        print("button pressed")

root = ButtonApp()
root.run()
```

I took the above sample code from this webpage: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-working-with-buttons-in-kivy/. As I wrote this is true for both Kivy and KivyMD and there is simply no reaction once I press the button.

I'm using Pycharm version 203.7148.72, Kivy version 2.0.0, KivyMD version 0.104.1.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: can you share your ~/.kivy/config.ini ? in particular the [input] section.

Comment: Sure:
[input]
mouse = multitouch_on_demand
wm_touch = wm_touch
wm_pen = wm_pen

Comment: i think that first line should be `mouse=mouse,multitouch_on_demand` are you missing the `mouse,` part ?

Comment: I edited the input entry to mouse=mouse,multitouch_on_demand and reset PyCharm. Looks like it's working again! Many thanks good sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer for more visibility since the issue was solved in comments.

Make sure that kivy input sources are correctly configured for your device, in the config.ini file (`<HOME_DIRECTORY>/.kivy/config.ini` see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html?highlight=config), is an `[input]` section.

On desktop, you usually want at least a mouse to be configured in this section, the most simple way to achieve that being a `mouse=mouse` line, with optionaly the `multitouch_on_demand` option (i.e `mouse=mouse,multitouch_on_demand`).